# What do the empty and full red circles mean in Qt Creator's Issues tab?

Tags: c++, build, qt-creator, qwidget

When you build an application in Qt Creator you can see the Issues you get while building in the Issues pane, at the bottom of the screen. So far I've seen the yellow triangle (warning), the full red circle (seems to be a compilation error) and an empty red circle.

While I'm pretty confident about the first two, I can't figure out what the empty red circle means, since the compilation doesn't stop but it's not a warning either. The circle appears next to some C++ lines of code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on the funnel icon on top of the Issues pane, I could filter out the output and see all the categories. It seems like the empty red circle indicates a Clang Code Model issue.